# Instagram social registration in Django

Tags: django, instagram-api, python-social-auth

I succesfully managed to login and logout instagram users in my application, but i want to create a new django user on first login, like "Register with Instagram", storing user tokens etc. to use their photos and data in my app

I'm totally new to python-social-auth, any tips on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you did everything(migrations) correctly, all those things are stored for you.

Here is how you can access `access_token`:

```
social_auth = UserSocialAuth.objects.get(user_id=id, provider='instagram')

access_token = social_auth.access_token
```

Then, you can use this `access_token` to access their photo and etc like this:

```
instagram_api = InstagramAPI(
        access_token=access_token,
        client_secret=INSTAGRAM_CLIENT_SECRET)

instagram_posts, next_ = instagram_api.user_recent_media(
            user_id=id, count=33)
```

Hope it helps